# How can I remove 1000+ Magento products without seriously damaging my store?

Tags: products, seo

I have a range of products that I feel are no longer required and are making my store's catalog feel bloated. These products don't rank particularly well on Google and have only generated a handful of sales. But my fear is that removing these will damage my overall site ranking with Google.

Does anyone have any tips for removing large amounts of products? What's the best procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

**For every single product:**

If possible, 301 redirect to similar product.

If not, 301 redirect to category.

Comment: What are the repercussions, if any, for taking this approach?

Comment: Well, this will make you not lose your linkpower but instead give it to a similar product or at least the top-category. The only downside I see is that  it will take some time for thousends of products.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, deleting products in bulk should affect the Google ranking.

If you delete products in bulk then Google will redirect the users to the 404 pages for those products. You may create 301 redirects for the deleted products to their category pages to avoid 404 error.

It is better to take advise from a professional SEO expert.

Comment: I mean in terms of my search engine ranking. I heard deleting in bulk is damaging but there are ways to offset some of that, with re-directs etc. But still, I know very little in that area.